# AndroidQuery ajax doesn't call php page when page contains IFRAME

Tags: android, android-query

I tried the following code to access my PHP page:

```
String url = "http://mypage.example.com/test.php?name="+data;
aq.ajax(url, String.class, new AjaxCallback<String>() {

    @Override
    public void callback(String url, String html, AjaxStatus status) {
        Log.w(Tags.DEBUG,String.valueOf(status.getCode()));
    }

});
```

My PHP page writes a file if the call was made. When I use the URL inside a browser, the file is created. When I use my Android app, nothing happens, the status code is 200. What else should I set?

UPDATE:

The source of my page:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>MY WEBSITE</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"></head>
    <frameset rows="92, *" frameborder=NO border=1 framespacing=0 cols=*>
    <frame name="topFrame" scrolling=NO noresize src="http://example.com/ads.php?ad=user12&cat=16" frameborder=NO>
    <frame name="user" src="http://example.com/user12/test.php" scrolling=auto>
    </frameset>
    <noframes>
    <body bgcolor=#FFFFFF text=#000000>
    <a href="http://example.com/user12/test.php">http://example.com/user12/test.php</a>
    </body>
    </noframes>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the web page was the problem, it sent back its source code and there was an **IFRAME** in it.